# Juxtaposing Replicate Data

Tags: r

I have provided a sample dataset that I have arranged in column format (called "full.table").

These data were extracted from a 96-well PCR plate, & while collecting my data, I always ran a duplicate experiment, meaning each variable (aka test) has 1 replicate. I would like to take all replicates and juxtapose them (have them be side by side), which would allow me to easily visualize replicates next to each other, and finally calculate an average value for the variable "Cq" between the two.

The complications stems from having done multiple tests over several days (complication one), and NOT having my samples always run in the same fashion on the PCR plate (complication two).  Typically, as you see on my data set below, Well A1 has a duplicate in Well B1, however this is not always the case.  Occasionally, Well A7 matches Well A8 (and NOT B7).

Replicates were always run on the same day, so an important variable here is “date” which I added via R before uploading to Stack Exchange.  I am confused on how to re-arrange the data to get my desired result (not even sure where to start)

I have provided an example of what I would like in the end, called “sample.finished.table”

Logically, having 768 observations in this example, this should divide it in two, resulting in 384 total lines of data (385 with header)

I appreciate any feedback.  Thank you

```
full.table<- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/kTQhuttv", header=T, sep="")

sample.finished.table <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/Phg7C9xD", header=T, sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` here to group by sample and extract the requested values:

```
library(dplyr)
full.table %>% group_by(sample,date) %>% summarise(
Well1 = first(Well), Cq1 = first(Cq),
Well2 = last(Well), sample1 = last(sample), Cq2 = last(Cq), Cq_mean = mean(Cq[Cq > 0]))
```

Comment: Hello.  Great.  I will give it a try, and get back to you if it works .  I appreciate your help :)

Comment: I ran your code today, and get the desired result...almost :).  I cannot seem to figure out why, with the above example, I only end up with 300 lines of observations when the starting number of observations is 768?  I would think that juxtaposing duplicates next to each other would reduce the number of lines observations by 2, resulting in 768/2 = 384.
Also, side note for the mean, occasionally Cq has only one observation (the other one being 0), could I add a line that says "IF one observation = 0, then consider the 1 actual observed value as the mean"? (i.e Cq1 = 0, Cq2 = 33, Cq_mean = 33)

Comment: Using `library(plyr) count(full.table, "sample")` you can see that there are some samples appearing more than twice, e.g. `H20-TypA` appears 14 times.
You can exclude values equal or smaller than 0 by adding `[Cq > 0]` to the mean. I'll update in the answer

Comment: Yes, you're right that H20-TypA appears 14 times, I should have clarified that this is simply because it was a control test repeated over several days.  Nonetheless, respective to the date of the test, it only was done twice per day.

Comment: There is still data missing in the final product.  Here is how to see it:

`x <- full.table %>% group_by(sample) %>% summarise(date = first(date),Well1 = first(Well), Cq1 = first(Cq),Well2 = last(Well), sample1 = last(sample), Cq2 = last(Cq), Cq_mean = mean(Cq[Cq > 0]))`
And then:
`table(full.table$date) #note 96 observations per date`
finally:
`table(x$date) # should expect 48.  Missing values add up to 84, which makes sense, since my output from the above code is 300 yet Im expecting 384`

Comment: have you thought about this issue that I posted above? I reflected quite a bit about it yesterday, but am still stumped on the solution.  If all else, I will post a new question to seek further help.  I'm very happy that my code has come this far with help from the stackoverflow community.

Comment: In that case, you can group it by `sample, date` to ensure each date is treated separately. Via `count(full.table, c("sample","date"))` I see 2 observations per combination of sample and date, that gives 334 rows. There are 96 rows where `sample` is `NA`, so that gives a total of 2*334 + 96 = 764 observations. Still 4 observations unaccounted for :-)

Comment: Addition: very likely somewhere in the `sample` called `empty`, since that occurs on 3 different days, with 4 observations per day. That's more a matter of data cleaning before using the function though

Comment: Hello, Great.  I will go through the code when I get out from the lab and see how it works. The data should not have NA's, however it's possible since an earlier version of the data did and I may have slipped past my radar.  Again, thanks as always, and I will keep you informed

Comment: OK:  First, I updated the file on pastebin yesterday, and adapted the code accordingly above.  I had NA's in a previous dataset when I first posted the question, but got rid of them, and therefore, the new link above should not have any NA's.

Your code works great!  I end up with 382 rows of observation, not 384, however, by running the table function  on your command (I just made a data set out of it called data.frame ) `table(data.frame$sample)` , I believe I have isolated the issue, and will be able to fix it accordingly.